# Why use different types of exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I can able to catch only one exception in java if my code is throwing an exception. But why we need separate exceptions (Nullpointer, classnotfound etc,.)? Is it Ok if we have only one exception rather that different type of exceptions? Please correct me if I am wrong.

My question in terms of code is below.

```
class Test {
    void method(){
        try{
            // some code....
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

If Java is allowing me to catch generic exception means why we need different types of exceptions?

Comment: If you want to treat the different exceptions differently, you have to know the correct exception.

Comment: To easily catch and handle different error conditions in different ways.

Comment: Its easier to determine what exactly went wrong. If you catch a `NullpointerException`, then the code already states what exception might occur. Opposing to that if you just catch a `Exception`, you can't know what kind it is, until it happens

Comment: Look at it like this: If you call someone for support with a problem you are perfectly allowed to just say "I have a problem!" and leave it at that without telling what your specific problem actually is. That doesn't mean that more detailed problem descriptions are useless. In fact quite the opposite.

Comment: I'm sure you could answer this yourself by reading and understanding the examples in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: The purpose of exception handling is to provide handling code in the catch block for the graceful termination of the program or to free-up some resources in the case of exception. Different exceptions require different handler code in the catch block.

Answer (score 7):

Bacause sometimes we need do different things with different exception.

```
try {
   doSomethingMightThrowException();
} catch (IOException e) {
    reConnect();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    createNewConnection();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    doNotCare();
    justContinue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer: it depends on your specific situation. Let's say that you knew you could possibly encounter two different exceptions: call them `FooException` and `BarException`. If you knew that when you encountered a `FooException`, you wanted to tell the user about, you may want to catch that exception, add some extra detail to it, and then rethrow it. However, if you knew that you didn't want to rethrow a `BarException`, you could have a separate `catch` clause defined that handled it separately.

So, to summarize, it's really up to how *you* want to handle the exceptions.